# ASP - Send data from UserControl to another one

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, panel

I'm contacting you because I don't know how to send data from a UserControl to another one.

Context:

The first UserControl, UrlControl (uc1) have a TextBox and a LinkButton who allow the user to add a URL to an Event (into my database.)

The other UserControl, TileColorControl (uc2) allow the user to add some colors in his Event. An added color may be attached to all urls or to a specific url.
In this controls, there is a DropDownList that contains the different url of the Event.

What I want to is: When I create a new URL by clicking "Add" (in uc1), the DropDownList (in uc2) refresh himself automaticaly with the updated data.

[This is what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow4wx.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

**UrlControl (uc1) code**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillUrls();
        }
    }
    private void FillUrls()
    {
        RepeaterUrl.DataSource = UrlController.FindByEvent(EventId);
        RepeaterUrl.DataBind();
    }
    protected void LinkButtonSaveNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string txtUrl = TextBoxNewUrl.Text;
        if (UrlController.IsValidUrl(txtUrl))
        {
            DMCAccess.Event evt = EventController.FindByUrl(txtUrl);
            if (evt != null)
            {
                btnMsgFailed.Visible = false;lbInfo.Visible = false;
                showMsgAlreadyUsed(evt);
            }
            if (!UrlController.IsAlreadyExist(txtUrl))
            {
                Guid userGuid =                      PersonsController.GetPersonByUserGuid((Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey).Guid;
                Url url = new Url
                {
                    Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    UrlLink = TextBoxNewUrl.Text,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    EventGuid = EventId,
                    CreationByGuid = userGuid,
                    ModificationByGuid = userGuid,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ModificationDate = DateTime.Now
                };
                UrlController.Create(url);
                msgSuccess("http://" + url.UrlLink + " was created");
                FillUrls();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HyperLinkViewEvent.Visible = false;
            msgFailed("Please, enter a valid URL.");
        }
    }
```

**TileColorControl (uc2) code**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillColors();
            FillUrls();
        }
    }

    protected void RepeaterColor_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DropDownList ddlUrls = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlUrls");
            ddlUrls.DataSource = urls();
            ddlUrls.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddlUrls.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddlUrls.DataBind();
            ddlUrls.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Default", Guid.Empty.ToString()));

            Guid? urlGuid = ((DMCAccess.TileColor)e.Item.DataItem).UrlGuid;
            if (urlGuid.HasValue)
            {
                ddlUrls.SelectedIndex = ddlUrls.Items.IndexOf(ddlUrls.Items.FindByValue(urlGuid.Value.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }

    public void FillUrls()
    {
        DropDownListBoxUrl.DataSource = urls();
        DropDownListBoxUrl.DataTextField = "Value";
        DropDownListBoxUrl.DataValueField = "Key";
        DropDownListBoxUrl.DataBind();
        DropDownListBoxUrl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Default", Guid.Empty.ToString()));
    }

    private Dictionary<Guid, string> urls()
    {
        Dictionary<Guid, string> dUrls = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
        foreach (Url u in UrlController.FindByEvent(EventId))
        {
            dUrls.Add(u.Guid, u.UrlLink);
        }
        return dUrls;
    }

    private void FillColors()
    {
        TextBoxNewIdColor.Text = TileColorController.MaxColorIdByEvent(EventId).ToString();
        if (UrlController.FindByEvent(EventId).Count < 1)
        {
            upNoWebsite.Visible = true;
            upColor.Visible = false;
        }
        RepeaterColor.DataSource = TileColorController.FindByEvent(EventId);
        RepeaterColor.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect these two controls at the parent level of the control hierarchy, using **Event Bubbling**.

I suppose your controls are both contained in another parent control or page, like this:

```
<control:UrlControl runat="server" id="uc1" />
<control:TileColorControl runat="server" id="uc2" />
```

First you have to declare an Event in uc1 - e.g. "OnNewUrl":

```
public event EventHandler OnNewUrl;
```

Then bind this event to method with desired functionality in "master" page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uc1.OnNewUrl += RebindTileColorControl;
}

protected void RebindTileColorControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // rebind uc2 here ...
}
```

More info about Event Bubbling you can find in MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644(v=vs.71).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720044(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that UrlControl should know about the TileColorControl that is there and should tell it to update.

Add a public variable/property with the type TileColorControl to the UrlControl class

```
public TileColorControl AssociatedTileColor { get; set; }
```

On the parent control/page you assign the reference to uc2 (the TileColorControl) to uc1's variable/property

```
uc1.AssociatedTileColor = uc2;
```

In the UrlControl you can use AssociatedTileColor to call the FillUrls method of the uc1

```
if (uc1.AssociatedTileColor != null)
{
    uc1.AssociatedTileColor.FillUrls();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do that:

TileColorControl: nothing to change
Event.aspx (page that contains user control), add public method:

```
public void FillUrls()
{
  TileColorControl.FillUrls();
}
```

UrlControl: In function Add or Update add lines:

```
DMC.Event currentEvent = (DMC.Event)Page;
currentEvent.FillUrls();
```

It's done, it update my DropDownList !